# Can Perl detect arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %x1 = ();
$x1{"a"} = "e";

my %x2 = ();
$x2{"a"} = ["b","c"];

p(\%x1);
p(\%x2);

sub p {
    my $x = shift @_;
    print $x->{a};
    print "\n";
}
```

which outputs

```
e
ARRAY(0x2603fa0)
```

The problem is I don't know when the input is an array or a scalar, and when it is an array I would like to print those values as well.

Can `p` be modified to do this?

Comment: => I encourage you to use longer variable and field names, it helps a lot with readability (especially when you come back to some code you wrote a while ago).  @Claudiu => no one appreciates your spamming the question; it's great that you like python, save it for the python questions

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, perl can detect what type a variable is.  Use the [ref()](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perlfunc%3Aref) function.  For example:

```
if (ref($var) eq 'ARRAY') {
   # Do stuff
}
```

See more in [this perlmonks discussion](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=118961).

Answer (score 17):

There are several ways to detect an array in Perl, each with different functionality.

Given the following variables:

```
my $array    = [1, 2, 3];
my $arrayobj = bless [1, 2, 3] => 'ARRAY';
my $object   = bless [1, 2, 3] => 'Some::Object';
my $overload = bless {array => [1, 2, 3]} => 'Can::Be::Array';
{package Can::Be::Array;
    use overload fallback => 1, '@{}' => sub {$_[0]{array}}  
}
```

- the [ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html) builtin function

  ```
  ref $array    eq 'ARRAY'
  ref $arrayobj eq 'ARRAY'
  ref $object   eq 'Some::Object'
  ref $overload eq 'Can::Be::Array'
  ```
- the `reftype` function from the core module [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html)

  ```
  reftype $array    eq 'ARRAY'
  reftype $arrayobj eq 'ARRAY'
  reftype $object   eq 'ARRAY'
  reftype $overload eq 'HASH'
  ```
- the `blessed` function from Scalar::Util which primarily is used to determine if a variable contains an object that you can call methods on.

  ```
  blessed $array    eq undef
  blessed $arrayobj eq 'ARRAY'
  blessed $object   eq 'Some::Object'
  blessed $overload eq 'Can::Be::Array'
  ```
- catching an exception

  ```
  my $x = eval {\@$array   } or die $@;  # ok
  my $x = eval {\@$arrayobj} or die $@;  # ok
  my $x = eval {\@$object}   or die $@;  # ok
  my $x = eval {\@$overload} or die $@;  # also ok, since overloaded
  ```

In the last example, the `\@` pair dereferences the argument as an `ARRAY`, and then immediately takes the reference to it.  This is a transparent operation that returns the same value if that value is an `ARRAY`.  If the value is overloaded, it will return the array ref that the module created.  However, if the value can not be dereferenced as an `ARRAY`, perl will throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the answer dynamically, use the `ref` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pretty print a variable, replace your `print ...` with `print Dumper ...`:

```
$Data::Dumper::Indent = 0;
print Dumper($x);
```

Output for your example would be:

```
$VAR1 = {'a' => 'e'};
$VAR1 = {'a' => ['b','c']};
```